# C++ Class functions into groups

Tags: c++, function, class

I am just here to ask if there's any way to group class functions in C++ into different "subgroups". (*SerialPort functions, DataManagement functions, Encryption functions, ...*)

I would like to use object to call that function from some "group" (I don't know how to call it)
For example saving current bool would be **obj.save()**  (*save() located in group named DataManagement*) or **obj.send()** (*send() located in group named SerialPort*).
I am just wondering if that would be possible, **to just group class functions**.

Comment: If naming the group is not required for calling a function, what's the purpose of those groups?

Comment: if you want to divide a class methods in groups, chances are high that the class is doing way too much. A class should do exactly one thing

Comment: Sounds like you need a SerialPort class, a DataManagement class, and an EncryptionStream class

Comment: Please read about [the single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle).

Comment: I would like to have those groups in separate files, it's just a design thing. I am just wondering if there's any way.

Comment: C++ is grotesquely modular. You can define a class and then spend the next hundred files implementing all of the bits and pieces. That said, the above comments are dead right. If you find yourself doing this, you've probably got other design problems you should address first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it by making a separat class for each group and multiple inheritance them

```
class MultiResponsible : public SerialPort, DataManagement, Encryption {
...
}
```

That way you are on a the way to Single Responsibility principle.

Comment: Thank you! Is it right to create objects only with derived classes? I mean, there would be only functions inside each category (SerialPort, DataManagement, ... ) .. So there's no point of creating their objects.

Comment: The functions would then not have any data to work with, each needs to have access to their relevant data, which could be done in their constructor or they could contain the relevant data themselves and only share some data.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather late answer but i think it might help other people wondering the same thing: **"Can I [logically] group class methods?"** - and the answer is **yes** -But- you won't get around a bit of code replication and storing one pointer per subgroup;
The solution makes use of structs to group in them the desired functions, which on initialisation take the pointer to the hosting class. And the best thing is: this can be nested.

Here is a code example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Super {
    int super_store_;
public:
    Super(int super_store) : super_store_(super_store) {};
protected:
    void report(const std::string& caller) { cout << caller <<endl; };
    int add_super_store(int i) { return i+super_store_;};
    int subt_super_store(int i) { return i-super_store_;};
public:
    struct subgrouped0 {
        Super* intern_;
        explicit subgrouped0(Super* super) : intern_(super) {};
        void call_report() {intern_->report("subgrouped0");};
        int my_special_fkt(int i) {return intern_->add_super_store(i);};
    } subgrouped0{this};

    /// here is the other subcat
    struct subcat0 {
        Super* intern_;
        explicit subcat0(Super* super) : intern_(super) {};
        void call_report() {intern_->report("subcat0");};
        int my_exclusive_fkt(int i) {return intern_->subt_super_store(i);};
        struct subcat1 {
            Super *intern_;
            explicit subcat1(Super *super) : intern_(super) {};
            void call_report() { intern_->report("subcat1"); };
            int my_nested_fkt(int i) { return intern_->subt_super_store(i); };
        }subcat1{this->intern_};
    } subcat0{this};
};
```

This enables you to write this code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Super super(4);

    super.subgrouped0.call_report();
    super.subgrouped0.my_special_fkt(0);

    super.subcat0.call_report();
    super.subcat0.my_exclusive_fkt(1);

    super.subcat0.subcat1.call_report();
    super.subcat0.subcat1.my_nested_fkt(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I agree with the earlier comments about splitting the class. But if you are sure you don't want to do that, then try this:

Declare your class in one header, say `megatron.h`:

```cpp
class Megatron {
// module A methods
public:
    void draw();

// module B methods
public:
    void send();

...
};
```

Then split the implemetation in file A and file B.

File `megatron_a.cpp`:

```cpp
#include "megatron.h"

void Megatron::draw() {}
```

File `megatron_b.cpp`:

```cpp
#include "megatron.h"

void Megatron::send() {}
```

The linker will sort this out for you, as long as you obey the one definition rule. Please go for multiple inheritance, if the "module" classes do not share state.

C++ lets you do this, but I urge you to consider splitting your class. Maybe what you're really looking for is a namespace?

Cheers!

Comment: Hello! Thanks for reply. I was reading a lot about namespaces and that was my original solution, but I found out that they can't be used with the class object that I want to save() or send() with. So that's the only reason holding me back from using namespaces. Anyways thanks for a great answer! :)